# how the base case D[0] is one where D[n] is the number of ways n can be expressed as sum of 1,3,4?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming

I am trying problem on dynamic problem which required to find the number of ways to find n into sum of 1,3 and 4.
i see solution on geeks for geeks.

base cases of the problem was d[0] = d[1] =d[2] = 1

how the d[0] = 1  where d[n] is the number of ways d[n] can be expresses as sum of 1,3,4.

d[0] should be zero as there is no way to express 0 as sum of 1,3 and 4.

this is the link for where solution is given.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-ofdifferent-ways-express-n-sum-1-3-4/

Answer (score 3):

> There is no way to express 0 as sum of 1,3 and 4

Yes, there is. The empty array is assumed to have sum 0. So choosing zero 1s, zero 2s and zero 3s is one way of obtaining 0 as sum of 1, 3 and 4.

Comment: Not just "one;" "the one and only"

Answer (score 2):

> d[0] should be zero as there is no way to express 0 as sum of 1,3 and 4.

This is matter of how you define it. The most convenient definition of "sum of 1,3 and 4" is "a value of the form *a* + 3*b* + 4*c*, where *a*, *b*, and *c* are nonnegative integers", and "way to express [value] as sum of 1,3 and 4" as the choice of *a*, *b*, and *c*.

You are apparently picturing a slightly stricter definition, that also requires *a* + *b* + *c* ≥ 1; that's not *wrong*, exactly, but it leaves you with more special cases to handle in your recursive case. It simplifies the calculations if you leave out that requirement.